# Converting VB.net to C# (InStr Method (String, String, CompareMethod))

Tags: c#, vb.net

Im new to .Net Framework
Can some one help me in converting this VB.net to C#

```
InStr(1, BLOCKTAGLIST, ";" & strTagName & ";", vbTextCompare)
```

BLOCKTAGLIST is Dynamic
Last argument is causing me a problem, else it would be done using `IndexOf`.

PS : I tried online converter, it didn't work!

Comment: `String.IndexOf()` it is not for C# only, its a NET method

Comment: You still can add reference to **Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll** and add the `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;` to your class

Comment: [InStr Function (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx) => [String.IndexOf Method (String, Int32, StringComparison)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224424(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Codexer That is probably the worst thing you can do in a C# application.

Comment: @Scott Marcus Of course, but **you can**... Give me explaination of why and also prove why it wouldn't work. I'm interested.

Comment: @Codexer But, let's not - - ever. In fact, let's not even bring it up.

Comment: The correct way is `String.IndexOf` as @IvanStoev mentions... The op asked about conversion there's not one as he still can use the vb.net one... He didn't ask what the alternative was.

Answer (score 1):

InStr returns a 1-based index, while IndexOf returns a 0-based index (this is why " + 1" is added below) and vbTextCompare corresponds to case-insensitivity (so OrdinalIgnoreCase is used below):

```
BLOCKTAGLIST.IndexOf(";" + strTagName + ";", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 1;
```